# Integrating lab notebook, experimental set up specs, behavioral tracking and ephys data in a neuroscience experiment

Tags: python, sql, database, data-storage, data-management

I am a Neuroscience PhD student. After asking around, both other PhDs and postdocs, and conducting an extensive web search, I am still unclear on the best way to organize data in my project, such that it is

1)searchable, e.g. I can query: SWR (electrophysiological phenomenon), rat, post_op_d4 OR mouse, score_4_ataxia, theta_oscillation and be able to see the corresponding bits of neural data

2)easily accessible even after I leave the lab

I need to integrate 5 data categories

1) Animal (.csv): animal welfare scores, tetrode position, behavioral performance

2) Behavior (.mat, .jaab): trajectories in the arena and results of classification of behavior from labeled frames from the video.

3) Experimental specs: condition, TTL pulses for stimulus onset and offset, trigger for start and end of the trial (not the same as the stimulus presentation time)

4) Neural recording data (.mcd, proprietary format): huge files, broken into chunks corresponding to trials during acquisition, but need to be stitched together for analysis

5) Plots of the processed data - tuning curves per neuron, occupancy histogram for the regions of the track, etc.

Now, the additional difficulty is that neural data requires heavy post-processing, cleaning and spike sorting. Spike sorting generates another heap of files of proprietary formats.

The question is two-fold
1. Storage: what is the best way to organize the data to ease analysis and search? Per animal? Per day? Per cell?

mouse1 === day2 === cell1 == spikes === figures

day2 === mouse1 === cell1 === spikes === figures

cell1 === day2 === spikes === figures (cells usually can be recorded from for one day)

In the analysis I need easy access to data per animal and per cell.

You would think that neuroscientists have already figured this out, but no, at least not in my department.

2. Management
   What is the best programme/file format to accomplish this?
   I have been circling around 2 options

2.1. SQL - Python

2.2. HDF5 with many tags and additional labels

Additional caveat: for now data acquisition is done with Matlab, while the analysis of the post spike sorting is carried out in Python.

I am just hoping that the programming community, which does not get bogged down in the content of the files, can see this rather trivial problem with greater clarity than i and my colleagues have managed so far.

Comment: I assume that your data comes in a certain way. You have a matrix featuring channels1-N, which contain a vector of values. These are then post processed for spikesorting, which gives you information streames averaged out per cell. So you now have another matrix containing averaged spike information per cell per measurement/ per animal. It seems to me like all the info you need is right there in the matrix. if you save your measurements in the size(n+1) row you will contain all data in a single matrix, where you can then compare rows and collumns depending on your question at hand?

Comment: Perhaps you could answer your own question to help us all, or explain the true question a little bit more. It seems like your data comes already structured. If you write your own analysis in matlab or python, structuring the data is a fairly simple step, since your just rewrite your analysis to accomodate the data structure that you get out of the gate. It becomes a bit harder when you are using analyses that are out of the box.